# Late binding/resolution by jvm helps prevent breking of code of current method for changes in class it uses

Tags: java, jvm, constants, late-binding

read it in jvm spec that Late binding/resolution of methods and variables by jvm helps prevent breaking of code in current method if there are any changes in some class it uses. This does not make it clear enough . How is late binding helpful in achieving this.

Late binding as i understand is just that a direct refrence to a type is kept in the pool constant just at the time a refrence for that type is first used in the code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a missing method or a method with a changed signature but you don't use it, you won't get an error.

It doesn't eagerly check all the binding on startup.

Comment: But if a method is not being used anywhere than changing its signature or its existence will not affect the code anyhow . Than how does late binding preventing code breakage comes into picture.when in such case even if binding is resolved for that method although that would be of no use but still that method will never be called from anywhere thus not causing any code breakage. Its a little paradox . Could there be any other scenario in which this line could make more sense and be helpful.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?  I am not sure what your concern is.